# Can't import the java.util.function.*;

Tags: java, netbeans, import

I am trying to use the java.util.function.*; so that I can use the Predicate interface. But my NetBeans says that the import package does not exist. Also, my Netbeans wants to import java.sql.rowset.Predicate; for the Predicate interface, which has nothing to do with what I need the interface for. I am using the interface so that I can pass a function or lambda expression through a parameter. According to my Netbeans, I have no updates and my version is 8.0.2, can anyone help please?

```
import java.util.function.*;
public class NumberingLogic {
public boolean checkX(Predicate<Integer> predicate){
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Which Java compiler version is your Netbeans using? `java.util.function` is only available on JDK 8 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Predicate` is a functional interface which was added in java 8. You need to install java 8 and point your netbeans to this installation.

You can do it through through the IDE itself: please see following [tutorial for details](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMUqIR8Pn0Y) (this is an [official](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-jdk8.html) documentation).

Or you can also change through the IDE configration files by adding `netbeans_jdkhome` parameter in `%NETBEANS_HOME%\etc\netbeans.conf` e.g.

```
netbeans_jdkhome="d:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"
```

Comment: You should do it via the Platforms menu, not fiddling around with configuration files.

Comment: @EJP partially agree that's why update my answer. But which option is preferable depends on you personal feeling. Someone like doing everything in console, others prefer using UI tools.